# "Стрим" экрана (демонстрация экрана). Android API: MediaProjection

Tags: java, android, потоки-данных, видео, udp

В [официальном Android API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenCapture) написано следующее:

"Метод createVirtualDisplay позволяет вашему приложению записывать экран в объект Surface, который ваше приложение может отправить по сети."

[image: картинка]
У меня есть [приложение](https://github.com/Android-Runners/RecordingScreen/tree/VladBranch/app/src/main/java/com/example/recordingscreen), которое при нажатии на кнопку "Начать запись" начинает запись экрана.

[image]

При нажатии "Остановить запись" - останавливает.

[image]

При нажатии на "Play" - воспроизводит последнее видео, которое было записано.

[image]

Код я <strike>скопировал</strike> взял [отсюда](http://www.fandroid.info/kak-sozdat-prilozhenie-dlya-zapisi-ekrana-android-smartfona/). Тут все вроде красиво и с объяснениями.

У меня есть сервер, написаный с помощью datagram сокетов, который принимает и возвращает пакеты.

Мой вопрос: как сделать "стрим" своего экрана (демонстрацию своего экрана)? Если делать это как-то через объект Surface, то как именно (есть ли примеры кода)?

P.S. Я читал в интернете что-то про Parcel.

```
Parcel – это контейнер для передачи данных.
```

Возможно ли его использовать для выполнения задачи?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось делать скриншоты и отправлять их. Сделал это через TCP. [Вот](https://github.com/Android-Runners/Screen_Sharing).
P.S. Приложение не доделано, но задача выполнена.